# How can I connect an Azure application using Windows Authentication to onpremise SQL DB

Tags: sql, azure, dml

How can I connect an Azure application using Windows Authentication to onpremise SQL DB.

I have a site to site connection established to a machine now I want to create an application using Windows Authentication and connect to on premise SQL DB and do all the DML operations.

How can I achieve this.

Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
Suresh

Comment: is the server domain joined?

Comment: No they are not joined